# How to sum information betwen 2 seq of Dates in r?

Tags: r, date, sum, conditional-statements

I have a dataframe whit dates of precipitation like this one

```
df_pp =  data.frame(Date = c("2020-04-01 11:25:25","2020-04-01 11:27:85","2020-04-02 05:23:25",
                    "2020-04-02 05:24:25","2020-04-25 11:52:25","2020-04-25 11:53:25"), PP = 0.2)
```

And I have another df like this one is a saquence by 5 minutes one month to this case april.

```
df = data.frame(Date = format(seq.POSIXt(as.POSIXct("2020-04-01"), as.POSIXct("2020-04-30"), 
                       by = "5 min") ,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz="GMT"), PP = 0)
```

I want to sum the PP of the first two dates in df_PP in mi df by 5 minutes for example the first PP hour in df_pp is "2020-04-01 11:25:25" and "2020-04-01 11:27:25", I want to sum the PP values of that dates in df$PP in 2020-04-01 11:25:00, but i have a looot of date so I can't put the conditional manually.

Can you helpme thanks a lot.

Comment: Please check your second example.  It is throwing error

Comment: Try now, sorry I miss the "" in the dates of second df

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the rounding functions in `lubridate` package directly onto your `df_pp` without worrying about matching with a second dataframe.

Convert Date column to Date Time object and use `floor_date()` to round down at 5 minute intervals:

```
library(lubridate)

df_pp %>% 
  mutate(round_time = floor_date(as.POSIXct(Date), "5 mins")) %>% 
  group_by(round_time) %>% 
  summarise(PP_5min = sum(PP)) %>% 
  ungroup()


  round_time          PP_5min
  <dttm>                <dbl>
1 2020-04-01 11:25:00     0.4
2 2020-04-02 05:20:00     0.4
3 2020-04-25 11:50:00     0.4
```